# Firebase: Authenticate an existing user using REST API and Firebases hidden Auth URL

Tags: rest, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

For the past 3 years we have used HTML/Js only with Firebase but now we are using Unity as well.

The current Unity/Firebase only works on Android/iOS when deployed and 99% of our work is on the windows store.

I've actually got a pretty decent Unity/Firebase codebase going but it requires me to use a full App Secret.

All the other libraries expose a method to login with Email/Password but the REST API only allows the use of a token or your app secret that it then states is ill advised to put into your client; I guess the thinking is if you're using a different library that you'll have your own auth/user method which we don't...

Now, I've pulled apart the web version and got this:

```
https://auth.firebase.com/v2/<myfirebase>/auth/password?&email=dennis%40<mysite>&password=<mypassword>v=js-2.2.9&transport=json&suppress_status_codes=true
```

So there IS an endpoint that I can send stuff to and I've tested it inside unity with good results.

Obviously the URL isn't guaranteed to stay working but I'm wondering if there is any reason NOT to use this?

Also, Why not just expose this endpoint in the official REST API?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, that URL will continue to work for your Legacy Firebase project. You will have to do the same sort of reverse engineering if you want to update to the new Firebase 3.0 API. However, if you are still using a legacy Firebase project -- I encourage you to take a look at [this](https://github.com/firebase/Firebase-Unity). It has not been updated to work with Firebase 3.0 -- so I needed to do something similar to what you did to allow login to the new API.

I was able to do this with the new API using C# as follows (where FirebaseManager is a Singleton I wrote for Global variables and functions to write and read from/to the DB :

```
Hashtable loginData = new Hashtable();
loginData.Add ("email", <EMAIL-GOES-HERE>);
loginData.Add ("password", <PASSWORD-GOES-HERE>);
loginData.Add ("returnSecureToken", true);
UnityHTTP.Request loginRequest = new UnityHTTP.Request ("post", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key="
    + <YOUR-PROJECT-API-KEY-GOES-HERE>, loginData);

loginRequest.Send ((request) => {
    Hashtable jsonResponse = (Hashtable)JSON.JsonDecode(request.response.Text);
    if (jsonResponse == null) {
        DisplayErrorMessage("Error logging in. Server returned null or malformed response");
    }
    FirebaseManager.Instance.idToken = (string)jsonResponse["idToken"]; // This is your auth token
    FirebaseManager.Instance.uid = (string)jsonResponse["localId"]; // this is your "uid"
});

// I have a list of users in my db keyed by the "uid" -- I access them like this

UnityHTTP.Request fullnameRequest = new UnityHTTP.Request ("get",
    <YOUR-DATABASE-ROOT-URL-HERE>
    + "/users/" + FirebaseManager.Instance.uid + ".json?auth=" + FirebaseManager.Instance.idToken);

fullnameRequest.Send ((request) => {
    Debug.Log(request.response.Text);
    Hashtable jsonResponse = (Hashtable)JSON.JsonDecode(request.response.Text);
    if (jsonResponse == null) {
        DisplayErrorMessage("Error getting user info. Server returned null or malformed response");
    }
    FirebaseManager.Instance.fullname = (string)jsonResponse["fullname"];
    FirebaseManager.Instance.groupId = (string)jsonResponse["group"]; // just storing this in memory
});
```

So I don't think there is any harm in using the URL, just make sure you budget time for more work when things change.